# Ambiente de Desenvolvimento Nodejs/npm/Cordova no Linux Mint

Tags: node.js, linux, apache-cordova, mint

No momento estou utilizando o Linux Mint 18.2 KDE e preciso instalar o ambiente de desenvolvimento do cordova, já que estou fazendo um curso do mesmo. No entanto já faz mais de duas semanas que estou enfrentando um problema muito chato com o download do cordova via npm vide imagem abaixo.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já me informaram que este problema pode ter a ver com a versão do Nodejs e consequentemente com a versão do npm. Porém também sou novato no mundo linux e as únicas versões que consegui instalar foram as que seguem na imagem.

Já instalei o NodeJs seguindo [este tutorial](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) e também instalei com o simples `sudo apt-get install nodejs` e a versões permanecem as mesmas.

Vale ressaltar que também não conseguido instalar outros pacotes com npm, os erros são sempre semelhantes.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro vamos tentar atualizar as *packages* do sistema para ver se há uma atualização ou para o NodeJS ou para o NPM. Abra o terminal e digite:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Isso atualiza todos os pacotes do teu PC.
Se você está usando uma proxy, deve configura-la com:

```
npm config set proxy
```